# Mysterious (to me) "object doesn't support this propery or method error - JavaScript HTML rollout

Tags: javascript, html, rollout

I'm getting the error above from Char 1 of the 4th line... No clue what's throwing it? I'm sure its something simple that I don't see...

```
out = out + "<b>Select Box Information</b><br><br> The name of the select box is: skeletor. A play on the word selector.<br>"
out = out + "The options for the select box are, Default Value, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4 and Option 5.<br>"
out = out + "The values for each option, from top to bottom, are: " + lucy.skeletor.option(0) + ", "
out = out + lucy.skeletor.option(1) + ", " + lucy.skeletor.option(2) + ", " + lucy.skeletor.option(3)
out = out + ", " + lucy.skeletor.option(4) + ".<br><br>"
out = out + "The index of the first option in the select box is: 0. The location of the user-selected option is: " + lucy.skeletor.value + ".<br><br>"
```

Comment: In order to help you we would have to know what `lucy`, `lucy.skeletor` and `lucy.skeletor.option` are. The error says that one of the two properties you are trying to access don't exist.

Comment: We need more information from you. What kind of plugin or framework do you additionaly use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think `lucy.skeletor.option(1)` will be the problem here. If `lucy.skeletor` is a genuine `select` element, it contains an `options` array. That array can be referenced like: `lucy.skeletor.options[n]`

furthermore, if you concatenate, you could do:

```
out += somestring+someotherstring+morestrings ... etc
```

Comment: my god you're right about the +=, I've been switching between VBScript and JavaScript for class and its making things fall through the cracks... I'll try the fixes you suggested real fast and let you know.

Comment: In this case it might be even better to use `[string, string, ...].join('')`.

Comment: Everything cleared the IE debugger, now just no HTML is rolling out :-\ I'll mess with it. Thank you Kooilnc

Answer (score 1):

out = out + ... is ok, just not necessary. 
Your problem is using .option(1) which is accessessing a non-existing collection

If skeletor is a  then the correct syntax for newer browsers is

lucy.options[1].value or .text

Here is what I think you meant

```
var out = "";
out += "<b>Select Box Information</b><br><br> The name of the select box is: skeletor. A play on the word selector.<br>"
out += "The options for the select box are, Default Value, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4 and Option 5.<br>"
out += "The values for each option, from top to bottom, are: "
var opts=[]; 
for (var i=0;i<lucy.skeletor.options.length;i++) opts.push(lucy.skeletor.options[0].text); 
out += opts.join(", ");
out += ".<br><br>"
out += "The index of the first option in the select box is: 0. The location of the user-selected option is: " + lucy.skeletor.value + ".<br><br>"
```